# Scaling masked images in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, masking

I have a masked image like so:

```
local mask = graphics.newMask("1_mask.png")
local image = display.newImage("1.png")
image:setMask(mask)
image.maskScaleX = image.xScale
image.maskScaleY = display.yScale
image.maskX = image.contentWidth/2
image.maskY = image.contentHeight/2
```

If I remove the code after setMask, the image appears fine, although it's quite too big so I need to scale it. However, if I trying to scale the image, it looks broken and it's way too small. I'm trying to avoid having to resize my images so it's my last option so how can I scale my image without it looking broken or ending up way too small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can shorten your code by using the following assignment schemes:

   ```
   local mask, image = graphics.newMask("1_mask.png"), display.newImage("1.png")
   ```
2. There is a [`scale()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/scale.html) method available in Corona. You can use it to set the dimensions as a percentage of original. For eg. to scale the image down to 50% of original

   ```
   image:scale( 0.5, 0.5 )
   ```
3. To preserve mask scale same as that of the `display` object, you need to set `maskScaleX` and `maskScaleY` properties too.

   ```
   image.maskScaleX, image.maskScaleY = 0.5, 0.5
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. One question though, would that autoadjust the scale for the mask to the same scale as the image? In other words, I wouldn't have to add the code after setImage on my sample?

Comment: Edited the reply @user1597438 to include your question.

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing. When I try to scale the mask like that, the image ends looking way too small. Does that mean that the mask should have a bigger scale?

Comment: @user1597438 Try not to maskScale the image then, and tell.

Comment: I think it may be because of how my code are ordered. It's add image, add mask, scale. I tried rearranging the order to add image, scale everything, add mask and the images look okay even if the image and mask scale are equal. I could just go with this but do you think there would be any issues if my code are in this order?

Comment: @user1597438 That is known as logic. `(^_^)` When attaching mask to the image, I think all properties from image are also assigned to mask(I'm not sure though).

Comment: I've been stuck with this for a couple of hours and I only thought of rearranging the code now. Still so much to learn with so little time. Thanks again for the help. :)